# java calculate total number of hours and minutes

Tags: java

I have these set of time

8:00 8:30 8:40 and 10:00

what I wanted to do is to sum them

8:00+8:30+8:40+10:00=35:10

is it possible to display or print a time greater than 24hrs?

it returns back to 0

```
private void btnCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String[] timeInAM;
    String[] timeOutAM;
    String[] timeInPM;
    String[] timeOutPM;
    Calendar time;
    for(int i=0;i<tblWorkPeriod.getRowCount();i++)
    {
        timeInAM=tblWorkPeriod.getValueAt(i, 1).toString().split(":");
        timeOutAM=tblWorkPeriod.getValueAt(i, 2).toString().split(":");
        timeInPM=tblWorkPeriod.getValueAt(i, 3).toString().split(":");
        timeOutPM=tblWorkPeriod.getValueAt(i, 4).toString().split(":");
        LocalTime inAM=new LocalTime(Integer.valueOf(timeInAM[0]),Integer.valueOf(timeInAM[1]));
        LocalTime outAM=new LocalTime(Integer.valueOf(timeOutAM[0]),Integer.valueOf(timeOutAM[1]));
        LocalTime inPM=new LocalTime(Integer.valueOf(timeInPM[0]),Integer.valueOf(timeInPM[1]));
        LocalTime outPM=new LocalTime(Integer.valueOf(timeOutPM[0]),Integer.valueOf(timeOutPM[1]));

        LocalTime intervalAM=outAM.minusHours(inAM.getHourOfDay()).minusMinutes(inAM.getMinuteOfHour());
        LocalTime intervalPM=outPM.minusHours(inPM.getHourOfDay()).minusMinutes(inPM.getMinuteOfHour());
        LocalTime total = intervalAM.plusHours(intervalPM.getHourOfDay()).plusMinutes(intervalPM.getMinuteOfHour());

        tblWorkPeriod.setValueAt(total.toString().substring(0, total.toString().lastIndexOf(":")),i,5);
    }
    LocalTime total=new LocalTime(0,0);
    for(int i=0;i<tblWorkPeriod.getRowCount()-1;i++)
    {
        String[] strSubtotal=tblWorkPeriod.getValueAt(i, 5).toString().split(":");
        LocalTime subtotal=new LocalTime(Integer.valueOf(strSubtotal[0]),Integer.valueOf(strSubtotal[1]));
        total=total.plusHours(subtotal.getHourOfDay()).plusMinutes(subtotal.getMinuteOfHour());
    }


}
```

Comment: ahm maybe just a System.out.println?

Comment: As **what**? String?

Comment: in any kind of variable I guess as long as when I sum the total time it wouldn't be 35:70

Comment: Need to see some of your code. Specifically the type of "set of time" you are using and the code that doesn't "print a time greater than 24hrs".

Comment: Show your Java code for calculating such sum.

Comment: @jdphenix the time will be based on what the user input for example timeINAM is 9:00, timeOUTAM is 12:00, timeINPM is 13:00 and timeOUTPM is 18:00 would result to 8:00 using subtotal=(timeOUTAM-timeINAM) + (timeOUTPM-timeINPM)
8:00 12:00 13:00 18:00 would result to 9:00


so I need to compute for the sum of 8:00 and 9:00 I still haven't find any way to compute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `String time1 = "8:00"` and `String time2 = "9:00"` then pass them through a method that gets total minutes. Then add them together and parse the final result ;)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String time1 = "8:00";
    String time2 = "9:00";
    int t1 = getTotalMinutes(time1);
    int t2 = getTotalMinutes(time2);
    int total = t1 + t2;
    String result = getResult(total);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static int getTotalMinutes(String time) {
    String[] t = time.split(":");
    return Integer.valueOf(t[0]) * 60 + Integer.valueOf(t[1]);
}

public static String getResult(int total) {
    int minutes = total % 60;
    int hours = ((total - minutes) / 60) % 24;
    return String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, minutes);
}
```

Comment: thanks :) I just removed the %24 in ur getResult so I can have more than 24 hrs

Answer (score 0):

split them up and put them into the arraylist.It's a better solution for array because you can expand it